# Clean data in SQL Query through VLOOKUP

Tags: mysql, sql, vlookup, lookup

I have a query that pulls sales data in the following columns:

- Date of Purchase
- Product ID
- Product Name
- Price

However, in the early days of the business some of the Product IDs have been entered in the wrong format.
At the moment I have an Excel file with the old/wrong IDs in column A and the correct IDs in column B.

I was wondering if there was a way to write a query that looks if the Product ID is in column A of the list. If True it will return the correct ID from column B, if False it will return the Product ID from the database.

In Excel I would do it in the following way: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Product ID,ID Fix SheetA:B,2,FALSE),Product ID)

Sample Data

```
#   Created On        Item IDs  Product Name   Price
1   26/02/2018 10:51    ABC1    Product Name 1  99
2   26/02/2018 10:22    G7781   Product Name 2  1299
3   26/02/2018 10:23    L5303   Product Name 3  165
4   26/02/2018 10:24    G9576   Product Name 4  1999
5   26/02/2018 10:26    ABC2    Product Name 5  99
6   26/02/2018 10:30    GGG1    Product Name 6  469
7   26/02/2018 10:37    T1283   Product Name 7  299
8   26/02/2018 10:42    L4505   Product Name 8  329
9   26/02/2018 10:48    L3007   Product Name 9  99
```

As you can see we use L, G, or T followed by a number for our products.
One letter for each of our three verticals.
However, some have been added with an ABC or GGG prefix in the early days.

```
Column A   Column B
    ABC1    L886
    ABC2    L5632
    GGG1    G7268
```

That's why I have this extra file with old/incorrect IDs in column A, and correct IDs in column B.

The result I want is to group the sales data by vertical (IDs starting with L, T, or G). But before that can happen I need to do some sort of Lookup to fix the incorrect Item IDs.

Comment: you could  import the excel file  in a temporary table  and do the work directly in sql ..

Comment: You can use CASE statement and specify condition for each incorrect ID

Comment: Unfortunately I only have Read Only access to the database @scaisEdge

Comment: There are a couple hundred of these incorrect IDs @Aurelian, so that will be a bit of a mission

Comment: then how you can updated .. if you have read only  privileges?

Comment: I can't update, and I don't necessarily want to at this point. I was just wondering if I could implement this 'lookup' in a query

Comment: I do not understand. How can you write a query against data that does not exist in database but in Excel, specifically the mapping table of incorrect/correct IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If correct values are in db

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t( id int, itemid varchar(20));

insert into t values
(1 ,     'ABC1' ),   
(2 ,     'G7781'),  
(3 ,     'L5303'),  
(4 ,     'G9576'),  
(5 ,     'ABC2' ),  
(6 ,     'GGG1' ),  
(7 ,     'T1283'),   
(8 ,     'L4505'),   
(9 ,     'L3007');

create table t1(Columna varchar(20),Columnb varchar(20));
insert into t1 values
(    'ABC1'   , 'L886'),
(    'ABC2'   , 'L5632'),
(    'GGG1'   , 'G7268');

select left(
         case when t1.columnb is not null then t1.columnb
         else t.itemid
         end ,1)  vertical,
         count(*) obs
from t
left join t1 on t1.columna = t.itemid
group by left(case when t1.columnb is not null then t1.columnb
         else t.itemid
         end ,1);

+----------+-----+
| vertical | obs |
+----------+-----+
| G        |   3 |
| L        |   5 |
| T        |   1 |
+----------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```